# Flutter Codemagic iOS testflight app store issue

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am trying to build and release my flutter app to the app store. I am using Codemagic to do so since I do not own a Mac machine. However, this is the error I run into every time I run a build:

> error: Runner has conflicting provisioning settings. Runner is
> automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing
> identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
> signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings
> editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities
> editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

I've tripled checked my configurations in codemagic i.e. provided both certificates, selected release built, completed App Store Connect etc.

I am frustrated at this point and any/all help will be grateful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles here with the same issue, the solution was to ensure that the bundle ids matched with the one on developer portal.